# How to add checkbox column to user dashboard - /wp-admin/users.php

Tags: wordpress

I am looking to add a column to the user dashboard (/wp-admin/users.php) in wordpress.

I want to add a column of checkboxes under a new column heading called "Paid"

Currently, my website creates a new metakey called "payment_status" with metavalue "done" when a user completes payment on the website.

I would like to add checkbox column to the user dashboard - with the checkbox empty if metavalue for "payment_status" is empty or not available. And the checkbox - checked - if metavalue is "done"

We would like to be able to check and uncheck the checkboxes from the user dashbord and it update the metakey "payment_status" from "done" to empty

Currently, I have added the following to create the column:

```
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', function($columns) {
    $columns['paid'] = 'Paid';
    return $columns;
});
```

But I am not sure how to code the checkbox. If someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: Check out my answer. Let me know if it is working for you or not.

Comment: Thanks! .. I tried your code. But it did not insert "payment_status" metakey and value in database for a user when I checked the checkbox and updated the user profile.

Do you know why the metakey was not ceated for user when box was checked? Thanks

Comment: Oh! It should. I tested the same with my colleagues and it worked for them too. You did add your portion of the code right? I have updated the answer let me know if it works.

Answer (score 3):

Check out my code I have added the solution. Hope this helps.

```
add_filter(
    'manage_users_columns',
    function( $columns ) {
        $columns['paid'] = 'Paid';
        return $columns;
    }
);
```

```
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'manage_users_custom_column_callback', 10, 3 );

function manage_users_custom_column_callback( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    $checked = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'payment_status', true ) ? 'checked' : '';
    switch ( $column_name ) {
        case 'paid':
            return '<input type="checkbox" id="your_id" name="your_id" value="your_value" ' . $checked . '>';
        default:
    }
    return $val;
}
```

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'add_custom_payment_checkbox_callback' );
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_custom_payment_checkbox_callback' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'add_custom_payment_checkbox_callback' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_custom_payment_checkbox_callback' );

function add_custom_payment_checkbox_callback( $user ) {
    $user_id = $user->data->ID;
    $checked = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'payment_status', true ) ? 'checked' : '';
    printf(
        '
            <h3>%1$s</h3>
            <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
            <th><label for="Payment">%2$s</label></th>
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="your_id" name="payment_status" value="your_value" ' . $checked . '>
            <br /><span class="description">%4$s</span>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            ',
        __( 'Extra Profile Information', 'locale' ),
        __( 'Payment Status', 'locale' ),
        esc_attr( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'payment_status', true ) ),
        __( '', 'locale' )
    );
}

function save_custom_payment_checkbox_callback( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    $payment_status = ( isset( $_POST['payment_status'] ) ) ? 'done' : '';
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'payment_status', $payment_status );
}
```